# Replaceing a string on a plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, tableview, checkmark

I am making some confing settings using a tableView using a plist File to fill the data I am working around this code about 2 weeks and this appears to work.

This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([[[week objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"checkmark"]  isEqual:@"0"]) {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [[week objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"checkmark"];
    }
    else {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [[week objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"checkmark"];
    }

    [[week objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] writeToFile:@"week.plist" atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"%@, %@", selectedCell.textLabel.text,[[week objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"checkmark"]);
    NSLog(@"Array de week seleccionando %@", week);
}
```

Everything seems to work fine on the debbug area (that's why I use the nslogs), and my problem is That  can't save the changes on the plist file, it seem it saving in some kind of cache or something like that.

**Update**

I've also tried with this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"week.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:week forKeys:week];

    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict
                                                                   format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                         errorDescription:nil];

    if ([[[week objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"checkmark"]  isEqual:@"0"]) {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        NSString *uno = @"1";
        [[week objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:uno forKey:@"checkmark"];
    }
    else if ([[[week objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"checkmark"]  isEqual:@"1"]) {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        NSString *cero = @"0";
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
    [[week objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:cero forKey:@"checkmarck"];
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", selectedCell.textLabel.text,[[week objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"checkmark"]);
    NSLog(@"Array de checkmarks %@", week);
}
```

And I have had the same result on the Debug Area:

```
2014-07-07 22:11:21.384 experiment table view[2264:60b] Thursday, 0
2014-07-07 22:11:21.385 experiment table view[2264:60b] Array de week seleccionando (
    {
    Name = Sunday;
    checkmarck = 0;
},
    {
    Name = Monday;
    checkmarck = 1;
},
    {
    Name = Tuesday;
    checkmarck = 0;
},
    {
    Name = Wednesday;
    checkmarck = 0;
},
    {
    Name = Thursday;
    checkmarck = 0;
},
    {
    Name = Friday;
    checkmarck = 1;
},
    {
    Name = Saturday;
    checkmarck = 0;
}
)
```

Which is the same result that I get

Comment: The `writeToFile:` method requires a full path, not just a filename. And make sure you are writing to a writable path. The app bundle is NOT writable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Plist is in the bundle, you cannot write into it. 'In the bundle' means that you create the Plist by adding a new file in XCODE manually.

You can only write into a Plist that you create programmatically. Such a Plist is not in the bundle, but in your app's document directory. The path of the Plist is

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = @"week.plist";
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, fileName];
```

Comment: I didn't know what bundle is :P

Comment: A bundle is everything in your .ipa file. You can change suffix of the file from .ipa to .zip and unzip it. After that you will see an .app file, you can right click it and choose 'show content'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sen I resolve this, his answer lead me to correct my code.

First I had to programmatically make the pList:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"week.plist"];

NSMutableArray *week = [[NSMutableArray  alloc]init];

//Here I add all the objects inside the Mutable Array

[week writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Then to write on the Plist by selecting it on the picker:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"week.plist"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"checkmark"]  isEqual:@"0"]) {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"checkmark"];
} else {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"checkmark"];
}
[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[tableView reloadData];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks, and I hope this code help someone.